# get full text of cheerio object

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I would like to load an HTML-Snippet in cheerio, then delete some elements, and then simply write the manipulated Snippet to a file.

Even though this sounds quite trivial, the cheerio docs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) don't say anything about how to simply get the full text from the cheerio object ($) without selecting some specific elements.

Here's my code:

```
let data = fs.readFileSync(pathOfFile, 'utf8');
let $ = cheerio.load(data);
$('someElement').remove();
fs.writeFileSync(myNewPath, $('everything that is left'));
```

any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just the body:

```
$('body').text()
```

You might need to remove script/style elements first

Comment: thanks a lot. this was so simple but so hard to find out. So in the cheerio object, the whole file always simply gets enveloped into a body tag?

Comment: No, that's how html works, anything displayable will be in the body (as opposed to the head)